# Cambiar estado filtrando dentro de efecto en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Una pregunta un tanto simple. Para un estado obtengo un dato filtrado. Y lo cambio con un efecto. Sin embargo siempre se borra el estado inicial y no muestra nada al cargar la pagina hasta que pase el efecto.

```
const [categoriesDescription, setCategoriesDescription] = useState(man[0].descripcion)
    const { categoryFast } = useContext(AppContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        setCategoriesDescription(man.filter(cat => cat.id === categoryFast)[0]?.descripcion);
    }, [categoryFast])

    return (
        <div className='categoryDescription'>
            {categoriesDescription}
        </div>
    )
```

La primera carga no muestra nada a no ser que borre el efecto.
Igual si no uso el filter y llamo a man[categoryFast]Funciona bien, pero claro no seria lo optimo.
O si uso una variable let en lugar de un efecto, funciona bien, pero tampoco seria una buena practica.

Supongo que es por el callback del filter, pero cual seria la manera correcta y optima de solucionalo?

Comment: El código esta diseñado para correr el efecto despues de regresar el JSX, y dentro del efecto se esta ejecutando un setState `setCategoriesDescription` es por eso que el estado `categoriesDescription` cambia de su estado inicial al nuevo estado de inmediato. Si necesitas que el estado inicial se mantenga ahi necesitas manejar la ejecución de `setCategoriesDescription` con un evento (onclick etc). Y por curiosidad  ¿De que tipo es `categoryFast`?

Comment: Es de tipo texto simple.
El problema es que obtengo el evento en otro componente y lo cambio con el context. Por eso lo ponía en efecto. Aun así se queda vacío al tener el filter. Cuando no uso filter si carga de nuevo. Pero no se si podría buscar de otra forma que no sea filtrando

Comment: Bueno hay que considerar que el estado inicial de `categoriesDescription` parece un string, pero cuando usas filter para el set `setCategoriesDescription` lo que regresa es un array, entonces `categoriesDescription` se convierte en un array ahi, y no se puede pintar simplemente con `{categoriesDescription}`